# Matching observations with similar characteristics

Tags: statistics, stata, matching

im trying to match variables with similar characteristics. By the way, this is the first time that i use any matching method, so please be patient.
For example i have a dataset with countries and a bunch of characteristics, and i want to group countries that share similar charactersitics.

```
+---------+--------+------------+--+
| Country | income | population |  |
+---------+--------+------------+--+
| US      |    100 |       1500 |  |
| UK      |    100 |       1200 |  |
| Spain   |     90 |       1100 |  |
+---------+--------+------------+--+
```

I have reading some literature and what i found is the "Propensity score matching" using the psmatch2 command in STATA and what i was thinking was to group countries with higher Propensity scores.

Thank you

Comment: This is likely off-topic for this forum. You need to define what close means and whether you have some fixed number of groups in mind. Is being 100 on income the same as being off by 100 people? I don't think PSM is what you have in mind since you don't have a treatment here.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1573356-matching-observations-with-similar-characteristics It's  always a good idea to tell people about cross-posting.